# Playing streaming video in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, streaming

I've written a WCF service that streams media files. I'm now writing a WPF application that consumes this service and have only just found out that the MediaElement does not accept Stream objects as input parameters for the source property.

I've been Googling endlessly for the past two days and have looked at several alternatives including the Silverlight Viewports inside WPF, VLC ActiveX controls, VideoRendererElement and WPFMediaKit. Unfortunately I've been hampered by lack of documentation and/or examples and haven't really made any progress so far. The fact that this is the very first time I'm using WPF doesn't help either.

To put it simply, what I'm looking for is something that comes with documentation or examples demonstrating streaming in WPF and, if possible, is also straightforward to implement. The solution doesn't have to be perfect; all I need is something that works.

Answer (score 5):

You could host a [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) inside your WPF app and supply the stream which you receive from your WCF service through an URL which is served by [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) to [`MediaElement.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source.aspx) .

Other options (though you seem to have ruled them out):

- http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/
- http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/

Not sure if this is an option for you, but there are commercial libraries for multimedia including video playback from streams in WPF:

- http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia-suite.htm#-
- http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk-net2.html or http://www.visioforge.com/media-player-sdk-net.html

Comment: The WCF service uses TCP bindings, and runs outside of an IIS as a Managed Windows Service. Would I be able to use TcpListener instead of HttpListener to somehow get the URL of the incoming Stream?

Comment: I assume that your WCF service return a a IStream - IF this assumption is true then you would just use the WCF proxy class to get the Stream and then supply that stream to either the libraries I mentioned and or "relay" it to an http URL inside you app with HttpListener and tell MediaElement to use that http URL... I strongly recommend using one of the libraries though...

Comment: I've never used the HttpListener class before, so I don't quite understand how I'd relay a stream to a HTTP URL. Is this what you mean? http://pastebin.com/iELVyybp

Comment: that is a first step, there are some quirks (problems) and inefficencies in that code.. but again I would strongly discourage this routs since using HttpListener is a permissions/rights issue (it basically is an "embedded HTTP-Server") depending on what permissions/rights your user has...

Comment: In that case, are you absolutely certain that Visioforge's Media Player SDK is going to allow the WPF application to play the IStream that the WCF service returns?

Comment: since I don't know your WCF service and I don't know which video format it delivers etc. I can't be absolutely certain... just download their SDK and try, AFAIK it can be used without registration in trial mode (you could mail them about a trial version/key).

Comment: Hi! Could u provide more examples around "host a HttpListener inside your WPF" , please?

Comment: @Peretz What exactly do you need ?

Comment: Well.. I need C# code for this:  "host a HttpListener inside your WPF"

Comment: @Peretz The link in my answer has a simple example with source code... do you need anything specific ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this using a pseudofiles, i.e. emulation of file system calls.

When a path passed, a media player firstly opens the file (CreateFile is called), then reads data from it (ReadFile is called), moves position within the file (SetFilePointer is called).

It just moves within the video file and reads required blocks.

For example here described this approach (file calls just mapped to appropriate IStream methods: ReadFile -> Read, SetFilePointer -> Seek, CreateFile -> Clone etc.): http://boxedapp.com/encrypted_video_streaming.html