# Playing a video file in server through WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video-streaming

I have a video file at my Server and the path to which resembles like `"10.151.98.82/Medias/New/Videos/001.dat".`

(Actually a video file but the extension is in `.dat`)

I have already built a `WPF` application which allows my users to enter the above Server URL and then let them to download it and then play it.

But my guess is that they `need not wait till the entire file gets downloaded; just watch the files on the fly`.

I have googled on `video streaming` but could not get a solid material to proceed on with.

*[Sorry, if the question is naive or needs modification, i will be happy to do that or move to a relevant forum.]*

Any pointers on how to do this is much appreciated.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136213/playing-streaming-video-in-wpf) question talks about WCF service and WPF application. But, I dont' use a WCF Service. The video file has to be streamed from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to play your file using [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). it also have many advance streaming and Trans-coding Options. you can play, save and trans code simultaneously. Once you are able to Play your file in VLC Player than i would recommend to use [`VlcDotNet`](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) for wpf application. Tutorial for hosting **VlcDotNet** is available in downloads